# Как в ffmpeg нарезать видео на изображения каждые n секунд?

Tags: ffmpeg

Есть необходимость нарезать видео на изображения по заданному интервалу с помощью ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -r 1 image-%d.jpeg
```

Это извлечет один видеокадр в секунду из видео и выведет их в файлы `image-1.jpeg`, `image-2.jpeg`...итд

Но если мне нужен один видеокадр в, допустим, 4 секунды, как это можно сделать?

Comment: -r 1 верни в вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Да, это можно сделать. Ответ нашел на [superuser](https://superuser.com/a/729351/1693728):

Необходимо изменить `-r n`. К примеру 1 кадр раз в 4 секунды будет как `-r 0.25`, а 1 кадр каждые 9 секунд - `-r 0.1`

В конечном итоге мы получим:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 0.25 image%d.jpeg
```

Comment: Я не юрист и не автор ответа на superuser, но разве вы не должны были указать ссылку на оригинальный ответ согласно лицензии cc by-sa?

Comment: @quswadress да, забыл добавить